# Regular Expression replace 2 or more with 2 or more

Tags: regex

I want to replace more than one space with more than one `&nbps;`, but if only 1 I want to leave it as a normal space.

Test Cases:

```
input     | desired output
---------------------------
a test    | a test
a  test   | a&nbsp;&nbsp;test
a   test  | a&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;test
```

In this particular case i want to preserve line breaks as well, which i will later replace with 
, so i'm only using  as my regex attempt

All I've got so far is `/ {2,}/g` replacing with `&nbsp;`, but i can't figure out how to make the substitution match the count found by the `{}` in the pattern. Is there a way to do this, or would it be better to do through some iterative process?

I'm using C# in this case: `Regex.Replace(input, @" {2,}", "&nbsp;")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a look around based regex:

```
(?<= ) | (?= )
```

and replace it by `&nbsp;`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DbwW53/1)

**C# code:**

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<= ) | (?= )", "&nbsp;")
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<= )` : Match a space that is preceded by another space
- `|`: OR
- `(?= )`: Match a space that is followed by another space

Answer (score 1):

As you want to replace every space where is accompanied by more spaces, you can use look arounds to target every such space and replace it with `&nbsp;`. Here is the regex,

```
 (?= )|(?<= )
```

This regex will not match a single space and only match a space which is either followed by a space or preceded by a space.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dbhn25/1)**

**[C# Demo](https://rextester.com/VSRM81944)**

Inline code for demo, in case link is gone for some reason after sometime

```
    string pattern = @" (?= )|(?<= ) ";
    string substitution = @"&nbsp;";
    string input = @"a test
a  test
a   test";
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
    string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Prints,

```
a test
a&nbsp;&nbsp;test
a&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;test
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the most technically efficient way:

`\B | \B`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/QnHQoz/1

Explanation:

- For some context, `\b` matches word borders, which are basically any points between word characters (letters and numbers) and non-word characters.
- `\B` is the negation of `\b`, which means it matches everything that `\b` doesn't match, and vice versa.
- Therefore, the pattern above either matches A.) a point between two characters of the same type, followed by a space, or B.) a space followed by a point between two characters of the same type.